# Ansible: a fast way to reload nginx if syntax is ok?

Tags: nginx, syntax, module, ansible

I guess I can use the shell module and to run "nginx -t" and then debug msg it and from that msg somehow use that as a condition to reload nginx. Something like "when: msg has "syntax is ok" then it would execute a task that reloads nginx.

But is there a faster and simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you try to restart nginx, it won't if the configuration is not valid, not sure on reload, but this is one way to do it:

```
sudo nginx -t && sudo service nginx reload
```

Then catch the output to know if it's been reloaded or not if you really need to know.

Answer (score 0):

@CzipO2, Yes it would be better to first check the status of "nginx -t", register it and on the basis of that result you should perform the next tasks.

If you face any issue in writing those tasks, we can help in solving that.

Comment: Why not to use simple:$ nginx -t && nginx -s reload ?

Comment: It's recomendable to first read the -t and be sure it's good and then reload.